# How to list call recordings in Nexmo?

Tags: audio, node-red, recording, vonage

I'm working on a voice assistant with Nexmo.
I use Node-RED to build the NCCO object including a record node.

In the provided tutorials by Nexmo, e.g. 
[Build Your Own Voicemail With Node-RED and the Nexmo Voice API](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2019/11/14/build-voicemail-node-red-voice-api-dr)
the directly download the recording to the local machine.

In my case, don't want to immediately download the audio file via node-red but let Nexmo store my audios and download them all together later through e.g. a Python script.

In the docs it says that *"NOTE: After your recording is complete, it is stored by Nexmo for 30 days before being automatically deleted"*.

Unfortunately, I can't find any reference about where the audios are stored in my Nexmo account and how to list all recordings/recording urls of a Nexmo application.

Thank you for any help.

Nina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there’s no way to get the recordings as a list from Nexmo.

What you could do instead is, capture the API response from the `recording` webhook and log it.
Then later on when you’re ready to download them, read it back to a `get recording` node.

If you connect a `debug` node into the `/recording` webhook, you can see the structure of the message object.

```
payload: object
   start_time: "2020-03-04T13:06:40Z"
   recording_url: "https://api.nexmo.com/v1/files/516f74a8-abcd-4270-b553-2582650a2e5a"
   size: 26478
   recording_uuid: "dbd3cb68-0a3a-4c89-bc2d-7c38abd2c497"
   end_time: "2020-03-04T13:06:47Z"
   conversation_uuid: "CON-93ef5eef-gg92-49ae-9e01-f3c782390dd9"
   timestamp: "2020-03-04T13:06:47.733Z"
```

You’ll need the `recording_url` to download a recording, but it’s good to keep the `conversation_uuid` handy, as you can lookup the FROM and TO numbers based on this.

I'm leaving a possible solution with Google Sheets below, as a replacement for the `/recording` webhook. Import it from clipboard into your editor and see the comment node for instructions :)

```
[{"id":"9198a326.cfb3e","type":"tab","label":"Flow 2","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"49dc7444.625ff4","type":"http in","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":"","url":"/record","method":"post","upload":false,"swaggerDoc":"","x":210,"y":380,"wires":[["21594561.f44c1a","47021216.a25afc","dc814f00.17fa7"]]},{"id":"47021216.a25afc","type":"http response","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":"","statusCode":"","headers":{},"x":610,"y":380,"wires":[]},{"id":"5371302c.ee3688","type":"getrecording","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","creds":"10de89c6.d1db3e","filename":"recordings/{{msg.payload.from}}_{{msg.payload.timestamp}}.mp3","x":1260,"y":580,"wires":[["6d03a7ed.2a6d7","38dd6acf.b46cae"]]},{"id":"21594561.f44c1a","type":"debug","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","x":450,"y":320,"wires":[]},{"id":"bcb08110.c2f7c","type":"e-mail","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","server":"smtp.gmail.com","port":"465","secure":true,"tls":true,"name":"","dname":"","x":1690,"y":580,"wires":[]},{"id":"6d03a7ed.2a6d7","type":"debug","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","x":1490,"y":500,"wires":[]},{"id":"38dd6acf.b46cae","type":"change","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"topic","pt":"msg","to":"'Voicemail from ' & msg.req.query.from","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":1500,"y":580,"wires":[["bcb08110.c2f7c"]]},{"id":"c8fadcb1.13aca","type":"inject","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":"Download/Send recordings in email","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":280,"y":580,"wires":[["af254a75.791888"]]},{"id":"f9706ea5.ea66","type":"change","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"{\t    \"start_time\": (msg.payload)[0],\t    \"recording_url\": (msg.payload)[1],\t    \"size\": (msg.payload)[2],\t    \"recording_uuid\": (msg.payload)[3],\t    \"end_time\": (msg.payload)[4],\t    \"conversation_uuid\": (msg.payload)[5],\t    \"timestamp\": (msg.payload)[6],\t    \"from\": (msg.payload)[7]\t}","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":1060,"y":580,"wires":[["5371302c.ee3688"]]},{"id":"9f017b25.db6fe8","type":"debug","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":970,"y":440,"wires":[]},{"id":"dc814f00.17fa7","type":"change","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"[payload.start_time, payload.recording_url, payload.size, payload.recording_uuid, payload.end_time, payload.conversation_uuid, payload.timestamp, req.query.from]","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":480,"y":440,"wires":[["c8118876.f668e"]]},{"id":"521189f7.2f6d8","type":"debug","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":830,"y":760,"wires":[]},{"id":"deba2a63.a4f4d","type":"split","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":"","splt":"\\n","spltType":"str","arraySplt":1,"arraySpltType":"len","stream":false,"addname":"","x":830,"y":580,"wires":[["f9706ea5.ea66"]]},{"id":"c8118876.f668e","type":"GSheet","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","creds":"90e07aa9.34a6","method":"append","action":"","sheet":"1mmXhj40aeSooxmtku3ma4auLyrHhJO8xCSQsklZ1_BU","cells":"Sheet4!A1","name":"","x":730,"y":440,"wires":[["9f017b25.db6fe8"]]},{"id":"af254a75.791888","type":"GSheet","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","creds":"bd7b95fd.c3dee8","method":"get","action":"","sheet":"1mmXhj40aeSooxmtku3ma4auLyrHhJO8xCSQsklZ1_BU","cells":"Sheet4!A:H","name":"","x":610,"y":580,"wires":[["521189f7.2f6d8","deba2a63.a4f4d"]]},{"id":"335f8e96.7242ba","type":"comment","z":"9198a326.cfb3e","name":" Instructions","info":"1. Install `node-red-contrib-google-sheets` package and restart Node-RED.\n2. Add _creds_, _SpreadsheetID_ and _Cells_ in the **GSheet** nodes \n3. Add your Nexmo credentials in the **Get Recording** node\n4. Configure **email** node or add download functionality","x":220,"y":180,"wires":[]},{"id":"10de89c6.d1db3e","type":"nexmovoiceapp","z":"","name":"New Voice App"},{"id":"90e07aa9.34a6","type":"gauth","z":"9198a326.cfb3e"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and the code snippet!

Comment: Similar to your flow, I was planning to store the recording information object into a Cloudant database to download it later on.

Now I see the problem, that the debug node from the record URL is not displaying anything in the debug console. It looks like nothing is been posted to /record.
To clarify, I don't model the dialog flow in Nexmo but use the "Connect" node to connect the call to a SIP trunk.
Is the recording somehow not working if I use the SIP? 
Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: Nevermind! We solved it by not only setting /record as the POST route into the Record node but the whole https://..../record